# Javascript to PHP input is empty. Live search PHP trouble

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When I enter something in input it is empty.

This is HTML form and JS

```js
$(function() {
    $("#search").keyup(function() {
        var search = $("#search").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "search.php",
            data: {
                "search": search
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(response) {
                $("#resSearch").html(response);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="search">
    <form action="search.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="search" id="search">
        <input type="submit" name="dosearch" style="display: none;">
    </form>
</div>
<div id="resSearch"></div>
```

> And the search.php

```
<?php
require_once 'functions/functions.php';
global $mysqli;
connectDB();
$search = $_POST['search'];
$search = addslashes($search);
$search = htmlspecialchars($search);
$search = stripslashes($search);
$results = R::findAll('games', 'name LIKE :name', array(':name' => '%' . $search . '%') );
closeDB();
$export = R::exportAll($results);
if(!empty($export)){
    $final = $export;
    var_dump($search);
    var_dump($final);
    $result = $final[0]['name'];
    echo $result;
} else {
echo 'No results';
}
?>
```

When i enter something in input and check it with var_dump($search) it says that variable is empty, but when i press enter key (submit), it redirects me search.php and there variable $search is not empty and it takes the value that i entered in input;

Comment: You have multiple element with same id, thats invalid.

Comment: Check why div and input field have same id name search..make it different.

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP. Purely an html DOM attribute violation. I don't believe it deserves downvotes though, because its a common error people make not realizing `id` must be unique across the entire DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have multiple id in a document. You need to change the id of the element to make them unique. I have updated your snippet and console log the search value.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#search").keyup(function() {
        var search = $(this).val();
        console.log(search)
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "search.php",
            data: {
                "search": search
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(response) {
                $("#resSearch").html(response);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search-wrapper">
    <form action="search.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="search" id="search">
        <input type="submit" name="dosearch" style="display: none;">
    </form>
</div>
<div id="resSearch"></div>
```

Comment: Finally, an answer that actually provides useful example data.

Answer (score 0):

@YourLogarithm, I see you have 2 elements with id = search, one is a div and the other the input. You can not have duplicated ids.